# How to transition from an iPhone only App to an iPhone AND iPad App?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

I know this question might have been asked before...

But since Apple is changing their ecosystem for developers as well as their AppStore policies so rapidly (and sometimes with breaking-changes), I would like to know reliable answers to the following questions. i.e. answers that are valid for the end of 2019 and also what the predictions are for 2020 (SwiftUI) to that respect.

The questions are:

1. **What do you have to do in order to get an iPhone-only app also to iPad ?**

   (I am not speaking of an App that shows iPhone-like on iPad - but a real native iPad App)

   **a)** is it enough to just select both iPhone and iPad under General in Xcode ?

   [image]

   **b)** do you have to create another extra AppStore App that is done for iPhone AND iPad ? Or can the existing iPhone-only App mutate to a iPhone-AND-iPad App without App Store submission issues ?

   **c)** will a) and b) be identical for the new SwiftUI world ?

   **d)** My current App is iOS11,12 & 13 compatible, does this cause any issue to the iPhone to iPhone-AND-iPad App transition ?

   **e)** Is there anything else to consider for the iPhone to iPhone-AND-iPad transition ?

Comment: All you need to do is check the box to add iPad support. You can always make an app store app *less restrictive* (I.e. run on more devices). You can't make it more restrictive (run on fewer devices)

Answer (score 2):

a)
1. Choose Project Navigator, Select your Project Target.
2. Deployment Info section, choose Devices. You will see 3 options – iPhone, iPad and Universal. Change from iPhone to Universal.
3. In the alert, Copy “Main” to use as main iPad interface. Select copy.
4. Under the new iPad group created, add new Storyboard file in Project Navigator. Name it Main_iPad.storyboard.
5. Change name of iPhone storyboard as Main_iPhone.storyboard from Main.storyboard.
6. Update entry in plist. Main storyboard file base name – Main_iPhone 
7. Add entry in plist. Main storyboard file base name (iPad) – Main_iPad. 
8. Add controller, outlet, action to Main_iPad.storyboard. 
9. Make proper changes to Main_iPad.storyboard to make it utilize the complete screen. Make changes in position, height and width of components.
10. Also, provide images for iPad.

Now application will be universal (iPhone and iPad).

Thank You !!

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanations. However, it seems to me that they must be different for iOS13 and XCode11.